# Why is are the keys on my MacBook Air so stiff?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I've bought an 11" MacBook Air a month ago. The <kbd>9</kbd> came out from the keyboard after few hours and I couldn't believe it. They gave me a new MacBook Air. One month later I'm using it and today the <kbd>T</kbd> is too strong to press and I can hardly type it.

I had another Mac before, and it lasted for years and I had no issues with the keyboard. This laptop never hit the floor; nothing's happened to it.

I can't believe I have to come back to the Apple Store and tell them the keyboard is broken again. What do you think about it? Is a line defect?

Comment: Actually now I've pressed the key "t" a bit stronger, and it seems better. However if I push in the lower-left angle of they key it doesn't work. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing the macbook air for the key "9" broken after one day, they replaced the keyboard for free last week for the second issue (the key "t" not working well). Great

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it, it's the first I've heard of any keyboard issues on any MacBook that I recall—the keyboards are traditionally highly regarded for quality.

I think sadly you've probably just had some bad luck. No matter how well designed it is, something as complicated and mass-produced as a MacBook Air is going to have some bad units.

You may want to try blowing some compressed air under that key though, it's possible that something is physically stuck under there, impeding the movement. Someone (ahem, possibly me) once ate a poppyseed bagel near my keyboard and a loose poppyseed caused some issues for a while before it got knocked loose.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to first spend some time at the Genius bar and ask them to show you how the keys work. Don't worry about the past for this appointment and focus on the problem you have now. You can then relate the past experience with the tech towards the end of the conversation to see how normal your experience is.

With the millions of devices out there, if there were truly a design issue, there would be a line out the door and around the block with people needing service.

It's entirely possible you just had bad luck or are getting some small debris under the keys. Even a pet hair in the right place can disrupt the exacting tolerances needed for the scissors to work if you pay attention to thinks like initial force to press and final force to press or compare one device to another side by side and study the key action with care.

Once a technician shows you the underside of the keys and perhaps your <kbd>T</kbd> key the cause of the odd pressure to activate should be clear to everyone.

In this case, you will see there is one spring that encases the key's electrical contact, four plastic to metal pin joints and two plastic to plastic pin joints. For the larger keys like the *option*, *return* or *space bar* there are additional metal struts plus larger and/or more than one scissor mechanism.

As with many things Apple, the devil is in the details and the details here are quite fine.

Comment: I wanted to add some general advice since I don't think it applies to @patrick - but may help someone else. Don't go in looking for a fight no matter how upset you are. Bring one small, observable problem and once the tech has observed and diagnosed it - expand the scope of the conversation. You likely will have an advocate that will bend over backwards to help you out instead of someone that first has to defuse "the angry" before even starting on the problem at hand.